# reddit scrapy xpath inconsistencies

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the following information from each reddit post:

post title : (contained in the following xpath as an example) :

```
<h2 class="s56cc5r-0 kTdpMJ">Japanese Weekly Tournament "Legacy Weekly Japan#142" is now live!</h2>
```

link to the post :

```
<a data-click-id="body" class="SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z" href="/r/starcraft/comments/9q30xf/japanese_weekly_tournament_legacy_weekly_japan142/"><h2 class="s56cc5r-0 kTdpMJ">Japanese Weekly Tournament "Legacy Weekly Japan#142" is now live!</h2></a>
```

user who posted : (contained in the following xpath as an example) :

```
<a class="_2tbHP6ZydRpjI44J3syuqC s1461iz-1 gWXVVu" href="/user/Horiken">u/Horiken</a>
```

comment :

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-click-id="comments" data-test-id="comments-page-link-num-comments" class="_1UoeAeSRhOKSNdY_h3iS1O _1Hw7tY9pMr-T1F4P1C-xNU _2qww3J5KKzsD7e5DO0BvvU" href="/r/starcraft/comments/9q30xf/japanese_weekly_tournament_legacy_weekly_japan142/"><i class="icon icon-comment _3ch9jJ0painNf41PmU4F9i _3DVrpDrMM9NLT6TlsTUMxC" role="presentation"></i><span class="FHCV02u6Cp2zYL0fhQPsO">1 comment</span></a>
```

All of these are contained under div elements wth an id attribute, so I start my xpath as follows:

".//div[@id]"

but when i do (for the post url for example) :

".//div[@id]//a[@data-click-id]"

I get an empty result back.

Even when I copy paste the xpath locations I still get empty resuts when I use scrapy response selectors. What is the correct xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an `id` attribute isn't enough. You want to specify what the `id` is, and what other attributes are.

For the post URL, if the ancestor's `id` value is `spam`, do this:

```
response.xpath('.//div[@id="spam"]//a[@data-click-id="body"]').extract_first()
```

[This doc](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths) is my go-to resource for XPATH quick reference.